# Unable to mount /export/home under Solaris after some disk errors on boot

Tags: solaris

uname -a

SunOS pyro 5.8 Generic_108528-14 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-100

I'm not on the console -- but a coworker told me the system had disk errors on boot.  All of the partitions seem to have mounted successfully except /export/home.

Whenever I try to mount that partion, I get the following error:

`# mount /export/home`

`mount: /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s7 is already mounted, /export/home is busy,
        or the allowable number of mount points has been exceeded`

How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be closed -- someone was in the /export/home folder.